# Why when I get my data seems undefined/empty? I'm sending data with jQuery.post() from JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

**My problem:** I am sending data to my PHP using jQuery's `$.post` method. For some reason, `data` seem undefined.

Let me explain how my code is structured ...

**1. I have the following button with an onClick function:**

```php
$data->acción = "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button id='modificar_$data->id' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar' value='edit'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button id='deleteID_$data->id' onclick='Delete($data->id, $tableName, $idName)' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons' value='delete'>delete</i></button></div></div>";
```

same code indented for better readablility:

```html
$data->acción = "
    <div class='text-center'>
        <div class='btn-group'>
            <button 
                id='modificar_$data->id' 
                class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar' 
                value='edit'
            >
                <i class='material-icons'>edit</i>
            </button>
            <button 
                id='deleteID_$data->id' 
                onclick='Delete($data->id, $tableName, $idName)' 
                class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'
            >
                <i class='material-icons' value='delete'>delete</i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
";
```

**2. My `Delete()` function:**

```js
function Delete(id, tableName, idName) {
    if (confirm("¿Estás seguro que deseas borrar el registro con ID " + id + "?") == true) {
        
        console.log("First parameter: " + id + "\nSecond parameter: " + tableName + "\nThird parameter: " + idName); // I GET MY FUNCTION PARAMETERS.
        console.log("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/?action=deleteRegistro&tabla=" + tableName + "&nombre_campo=" + idName + "&id=" + id); // I GENERATE MY POST URL CORRECTLY.
            
        $.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/?action=deleteRegistro&tabla=" + tableName + "&nombre_campo=" + idName + "&id=" + id, function(data) {
            console.log("My data: " + data);
            if(data == 1) {
                console.log("Data OK");
                //$().hide();
            }
            else if (data == '') {
                console.log("Data empty");
            }
            else if (data == null) {
                console.log("Data null");
            }
            else if (data) {
                console.log("Data exist");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Other reasons");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**3. So you can see what the `console.log()` returns:**

[image]

Why is `data` not defined?

**EDIT:** This is my full code: (I didn't want to upload the full code so as not to create confusion, I tried to minimize and compress it).

```
<?php

    use GuzzleHttp\json_decode;
    include_once(DIR_PLUGINS.'/alexcrudgenerator/main.php');

    $test = new GenerateCrud($_POST['tableName'], $_POST['id'], $_POST['tableFields']);

    $action = $_POST['action'];
    if(empty($action)){
        $GET = get_vars_for_get();
        $action = $GET['action'];
    }
    
    switch($action){

        case 'datosTabla': // OK.

            //print_r($_POST['action']);
            $res = json_decode($_POST['datos']);
            echo json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

            break;

        case 'deleteRegistro':
            //die("Hola");
            $tableName = $_POST['tableName']; // Nombre de la tabla de la base de datos (String).
            $id = $_POST['id'];               // ID (int).
            $idName = $_POST['idName'];       // Nombre del campo ID (String).
            
            echo $tableName;

            //echo deleteRegistro($tableName, $id, $idName);
            
            break;

        case 'showtable': // OK.

            $res = getEntireTable($_POST['tableName'], $_POST['id'], $_POST['tableFields']);
            $tableName = $_POST['tableName'];
            $tableName = json_encode($tableName);

            //$field = json_decode($_POST['tableFields'],1)[0];
            //$field = json_encode($field);
            
            $idName = $_POST['id'];
            $idName = json_encode($idName);

            foreach ($res as $data){                
                $data->acción = "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button id='modificar_$data->id' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar' value='edit'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button id='deleteID_$data->id' onclick='Delete($data->id, $tableName, $idName)' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons' value='delete'>delete</i></button></div></div>";
                $resultados['data'][] = $data;
            }

            $resultados = json_encode($resultados); // 7 PROPIEDADES

            foreach(json_decode($_POST['tableFields']) as $columnsDB){
                $fields[] = array('data'=>$columnsDB);
            }

            $fields[]['data'] = 'acción';
            $fields = json_encode($fields);
            
?>
            <head>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>

            <div class="container caja">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div>
                            <table id="tablaUsuarios" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed hover" style="width:100%" >
                                <thead class="text-center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <?php
                                            foreach (json_decode($_POST['tableFields']) as $columnsTH){
                                                 echo '<th>' . strtoupper($columnsTH) . '</th>';
                                            }
                                            echo '<th>ACCIÓN</th>';
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>

                function Delete(id, tableName, idName){
                    if (confirm("¿Estás seguro que deseas borrar el registro con ID " + id + "?") == true) {
                        
                        console.log("First parameter: " + id + "\nSecond parameter: " + tableName + "\nThird parameter: " + idName); // I GET MY DATA CORRECTLY.
                        console.log("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/?action=deleteRegistro&tabla=" + tableName + "&nombre_campo=" + idName + "&id=" + id); // I GET MY DATA CORRECTLY.

                        $.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/?action=deleteRegistro&tabla=" + tableName + "&nombre_campo=" + idName + "&id=" + id, function(data){
                            
                            console.log("Typeof: " + typeof(data));
                            console.log("My data: " + data);
                            console.log("My data: ", data);
                            console.log("[" + data + "]")
                            
                            if(data == 1){
                                console.log("Data OK");
                                //$().hide();
                            }
                            else if (data == ''){
                                console.log("Data empty");
                            }
                            else if (data == null) {
                                console.log("Data null");
                            }
                            else if (data) {
                                console.log("Data exist");
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("Other reasons");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var datos= <?=$resultados?>;
                    var dynamicColumns = <?=$fields?>;
                    datos = JSON.stringify(datos);

                    $('#tablaUsuarios').DataTable({
                        "language": {"url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/Spanish.json"},
                        "paging": true,
                        "lengthChange": true,
                        "searching": true,
                        "info": true,
                        "autoWidth": true,
                        "scrollX": true,

                        "ajax":{
                            "url": '<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/',
                            "method": 'POST',
                            "data":{action: "datosTabla", datos: datos}
                        },

                        "columns": dynamicColumns
                    });
                })
            </script>
<?php
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: maybe use `console.log(data);` to see if the output is as expected?

Comment: `data` is not undefined, that's the problem. You have something there.

Comment: If I try to print data, I only see blank. @DuchyWare

Comment: @nitrin0 I edited my code and image, check it, my `data` seem empty, right?

Comment: I am not familiar with jQuery but is `$.post()` the correct method to send parameters via a query string? Shouldn't you use `$get()`?

Comment: @secan Unfortunately I have to use POST :(

Comment: _“my data seem empty, right? ”_ - no, it doesn’t, it appears to contain the text `No data`. Because if that was not what your server responded with, then where should that exact text be coming from? It is not contained in your JS code anywhere.

Comment: In general: use `console.log("My data: ", data);` to output to the console, don't concatenate.  Though in this case you might like to do `console.log("[" + data + "]")` so you can see explicitly what the value is.  Or actually debug it properly.

Comment: Relevant: [jquery $.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType) - `jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )` depends on how your service method is defined, but you should be passing the data as the data parameter.  So could be your service (not provided) is expecting a POST *`body`*  - as you've said it must be a POST, it's likely the data must be in the body, not the url.

Comment: As noted above, "No data" is not an option in your console.log if/else - please provide the actual relevant code.   If `data` was "not defined" then you would get the "Data null" `else`:  https://jsfiddle.net/7oj5fy4n/

Comment: Try changing your $.post to: `$.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/", new { action:deleteRegistro, tabla:tableName, bombre_campo:idName, id:id }, function(data) { console.log("result:", data); });`

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you for your efforts. Trying what you said me in your last message, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteRegistro is not defined`. I will edite my question with my full code

Comment: My sample was just quickly typed into a comment to give you the *idea* / format of how to provide the data parameter.  You really should be able to determine from `deleteRegistro is not defined` that it should be `action:"deleteRegistro"` not just copy+paste then throw your hands in the air!

Comment: As suggested above, AFAIK, `$_POST['tablename']` does not take it from the URL.   It needs to be in the POST body.  A php developer should be able to confirm,  Quickest I found quickly was a question asking [how to pass POST parameters in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210900/how-can-i-pass-post-parameters-in-a-url), which implies that they're not normally picked up.

Comment: @freedomn-m Hahaha, I don't usually do copy and paste, but I'm saturated xd, sorry. Now I get `Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)} is not a constructor`.

Comment: Now that was my bad- remove the `new {` keyword,  `$.post(url, { action:"action", tabla:tableName...`

Comment: Or look at the examples on the jquery $.post page: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post

Comment: Try instead `console.log("My data " + (typeof(data) == "undefined" ? "is undefined" : "is the " + typeof(data) + " " + data));`

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to get data back, use `$.get`

```
$.get("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/?action=deleteRegistro&tabla=" + tableName + "&nombre_campo=" + idName + "&id=" + id, function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use POST. I am creating a CRUD table and I have a giant case where the `action` that is sent by `POST` is evaluated. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Note that a POST can/will also return a response.  There's no need to use GET to "get data back".

Answer (score 0):

The URL you gave in the function Delete() is wrong totally,

```
<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/?action=deleteRegistro&tabla=" + tableName + "&nombre_campo=" + idName + "&id=" + id
```

this URl works for GET method not post, for posting any content you don't need to put data into URL.

```
$.post("<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/", { 
            action: "deleteRegistro",
            id: id,
            tableName: tableName,
            field: field
        }, function (data, status){
                if (status === 'error') {
                    console.log("Not deleted");
                }
                else if (status === 'success') {
                    console.log("Deleted successfully");                                
                }
                if(data != '') console.log("The response is" + data);
                else console.log("There is not response");
            });
```

Here the `function(data, status)` is meant for error handing where `data` is the response from the URL and `status` is the status of data sent to the URL.

You have to be careful giving conditions `if(data == 1)` where `data` is the response from the URL so it isn't Boolean.

It is very important to handle the request at the other hand where the data is posted so do check it once.

For more info on `$.post()` visit [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-post-method)